# Triggering Airflow DAG via API

Tags: authentication, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

I have installed Airflow 2.0.1 on EC2 with PostgreSQL RDS as metadata db.  I want to trigger DAG from Lambda so tried to test the code with curl but am receiving Unauthorized as response.  What if anything should I be doing differently?

Steps:

1. Create user for lambda

```
airflow users create -u lambda_user -p some_pwd -f Lambda -l User -r User -e someone@nowhere.com
```

2. Define variables on shell (for lambda user, password and endpoint url)
3. Make the curl call

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic Base64(username:password)" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET --user "${LAMBDA_USER}:${LAMBDA_PWD}" "${ENDPOINT_URL}/api/v1/dags/sns_test/dagRuns"
```

Response I receive is this:

```
{
 "detail": null,
 "status": 401,
 "title": "Unauthorized",
 "type": "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/Unauthenticated"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After revising call to

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"
-X POST --user "${LAMBDA_USER}:${LAMBDA_PWD}" "${ENDPOINT_URL}/api/v1/dags/sns_test/dagRuns" -d '{"conf": {}}'
```

dag was triggered!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a user with the role `User`.
This is because you have `-r User` in the command.

Now Airflow requires at least `Viewer` permissions for the end point you are calling. You can find that information on the Apache Airflow website [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/security/access-control.html#resource-based-permissions).

If you change your command it will work.
Change it from

```
airflow users create -u lambda_user -p some_pwd -f Lambda -l User -r User -e someone@nowhere.com
```

to

```
airflow users create -u lambda_user -p some_pwd -f Lambda -l User -r Viewer -e someone@nowhere.com
```

Comment: Actually I got it working after removing Authorization from header.  However, looks like **used** API is just to get list of runs for the dag.  I need to find the api or function that instead allows to **trigger** the DAG.