# How to trigger DAG in Airflow everytime an external event state is True (Event based triggering)

Tags: python, python-3.x, event-handling, airflow

The basic concept of Airflow does not allow triggering a Dag on an irregular interval.
Actually, I want to trigger a dag every time a new file is placed on a remote server (like HTTPS, sftp, s3 ...)
But Airflow requires a defined data_interval. Using e.g. HttpSensor works only once during the scheduled time window. In my current example, I am using redis to persist the current file state.

```py
""" DAG for operational District heating """
import json
from datetime import datetime

import redis
import requests
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.aws_lambda import AwsLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator
from airflow.providers.http.sensors.http import HttpSensor


def check_up_for_new_file(
        response: requests.models.Response,
) -> bool:
    """ uses redis to check if a new file is on the server"""
    current_header = {
        key.decode() if isinstance(key, bytes) else key: value.decode() if isinstance(value, bytes) else value
        for key, value in response.headers.items()
    }

    conn = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379)
    recent_header = conn.hgetall("header_dict")

    recent_header = {
        key.decode() if isinstance(key, bytes) else key: value.decode() if isinstance(value, bytes) else value
        for key, value in recent_header.items()
    }

    if 'Content-Length' not in recent_header.keys():
        conn.hmset("header_dict", current_header)
        return False

    if recent_header['Content-Length'] != current_header['Content-Length']:
        conn.hmset("header_dict", current_header)
        return True
    else:
        return False


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['info@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'concurrency': 6
}

with DAG(
        dag_id='check_ext',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 11, 24),
        tags=['test'],
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
) as dag:
    check_for_new_file = HttpSensor(
        task_id='check_up_for_new_file',
        http_conn_id='_conn_id',
        endpoint='<some-url>',
        poke_interval=20,
        dag=dag,
        response_check=check_up_for_new_file
    )
    invoke_lambda_function = AwsLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator(
        task_id='run_process_with_external_files',
        function_name='LAMBDA_FUNCTION',
        payload=json.dumps({"source_type": "some stuff"}),
    )
    check_for_new_file >> invoke_lambda_function
```

How does this dag restart after success to check again for new files?

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the question itself, airflow is not an event based triggered system, and it's main paradigm is to do a pre-scheduled batch processing.
Nervertheless, it's definitely achievable, in multiple ways:

1. As suggested in the answer by @dl.meteo, you can run a sensor (there are many supported, HTTP, FTP, FTPS and etc..) in a endless loop in a pre-defined interval (every 30s, every minute and such..) and when sensor is fired up (task successfully completes), you can trigger a specific dag (with TriggerDagRunOperator). This approach has a downside - it will hold airflow's resources forever, and while it can be good for several lone use case, it's definitely NOT scalalble to use with hundreds of dags.
2. A better approach IMHO would be:
   a. to use Airflow's REST API, to trigger a specific dag (external
   event system directly calls airflow's REST API)
   b. if external event system has a webhook system, use it to PUSH    the event to a queue (e.g. kinesis) and calls airflow's REST
   API (to    trigger a specific dag)
   c. in case there is no webhook system, use a lambda (or a light    docker container service) to PULL for new events from your external
   event system (on a schduledqpre-defined period of time), and calls airflow's REST API (to trigger a specific
   dag)

https://brocktibert.com/post/trigger-airflow-dags-via-the-rest-api/

[Triggering Airflow DAG via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69671029/triggering-airflow-dag-via-api)

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care of the following two points to have a Dag that runs every time a sensor recognizes an external event.

1. `schedule_interval`: Use the preset None
2. Use `TriggerDagRunOperator`

It is by design to create an infinite loop to check out the external

```py
""" DAG for operational District heating """
import json
from datetime import datetime

import redis
import requests
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.aws_lambda import AwsLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator
from airflow.providers.http.sensors.http import HttpSensor
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator


def check_up_for_new_file(
        response: requests.models.Response,
) -> bool:
    """ uses redis to check if a new file is on the server"""
    current_header = {
        key.decode() if isinstance(key, bytes) else key: value.decode() if isinstance(value, bytes) else value
        for key, value in response.headers.items()
    }

    conn = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379)
    recent_header = conn.hgetall("header_dict")

    recent_header = {
        key.decode() if isinstance(key, bytes) else key: value.decode() if isinstance(value, bytes) else value
        for key, value in recent_header.items()
    }

    if 'Content-Length' not in recent_header.keys():
        conn.hmset("header_dict", current_header)
        return False

    if recent_header['Content-Length'] != current_header['Content-Length']:
        conn.hmset("header_dict", current_header)
        return True
    else:
        return False


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['info@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'concurrency': 6
}

with DAG(
        dag_id='check_ext',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 11, 24),
        tags=['test'],
        catchup=False,
        schedule_interval=None,
        default_args=default_args,
) as dag:
    check_for_new_file = HttpSensor(
        task_id='check_up_for_new_file',
        http_conn_id='_conn_id',
        endpoint='<some-url>',
        poke_interval=20,
        dag=dag,
        response_check=check_up_for_new_file
    )
    invoke_lambda_function = AwsLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator(
        task_id='run_process_with_external_files',
        function_name='LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME',
        payload=json.dumps({"source_type": "some stuff"}),
    )
    restart_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='restart_dag',
        trigger_dag_id='check_ext',
        dag=dag
    )
    check_for_new_file >> invoke_lambda_function >> restart_dag
```

For some of you not familiar with `HttpSensor`. The base path to the server has to be defined as an environment variable with `AIRFLOW_CONN_{_CONN_ID}=https://remote_server.com`. Then you can call the connection by matching the `_CONN_ID`.